# GDAL compilation with PDF support

Tags: gdal, pdf, windows

I am trying to compile GDAL with support to convert to PDF format. When I try `gdalinfo --formats` the option for PDF is not present. I am using 2.1.2. The command I am using to build GDAL is `nmake /f makefile.vc WIN64=YES`. Is it possible to convert raster data to PDF format using GDAL?

Comment: Have you been reading the manual http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html?

Comment: While GDAL is GIS software, and compiling it may sometimes be on topic here, you are liking facing issues with the dependencies (getting them installed/built/etc.) and those questions would be better suited for other sites.

Comment: Yes, and I did read that writing requires no backend support.

Answer (score 1):

PDF support is available on my version of GDAL (GDAL 1.11.5, released 2016/07/01). Try updating your version of GDAL. Also, see the GDAL documentation on [Geospatial PDF](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html) support. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
gdal_translate -of PDF main_raster.tif my.pdf -co LAYER_NAME=main_raster
               -co EXTRA_RASTERS=another_raster.tif -co EXTRA_RASTERS_LAYER_NAME=another_raster
               -co OFF_LAYERS=another_raster -co EXCLUSIVE_LAYERS=main_raster,another_raster
```